# Echo 1 number from databse row which has other numbers separated by commas

Tags: php, mysql

There's a rows called "ads" which contains user submitted IDs which are separated by commas, e.g. "24,56,67".
I want to echo one random number from that row, e.g. 56.
How would I go about doing this?
I already got all the numbers from the page. However, rand() doesn't seem to work, it's not separating and it echoes all the number "24, 56, 67" as is. Not separated. Not random. ?

What I have so far:

```
    $rotation_id = $_GET["ari"];
    $find_ad = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `rotations` WHERE id='$rotation_id' ORDER BY rand()");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_ad)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $ads = $row['ads'];
    $user = $row['user'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    }
    $advert = str_replace(',', ', ', rand($ads));
    $limit = 0;
    $ad = array($advert);
    echo $ad;
```

You can test it yourself to see the ads process and the rotation part ( http://www.fordberg.com/adsol )

Comment: what yo have tried so far?

Comment: you want to print any one random value from the list of rows. right?

Comment: @Boopathi Yes but someone already solved it. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I already got all the numbers from the page.

Then you can do

```
$string="24,56,67";                        // Your numbers
$numbers=explode(",",$string);             // Create an array of them
echo $numbers[rand(0,count($numbers)-1)];  // Display one random number from that array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$rowIds  = "24,66,25";    //Assuming You got rows containing all ids.
$idArray= explode(",", $rowIds); //Explode each id into an array.
echo $idArray[array_rand($idArray)]; //Getting random id out of an array.
?>
```

See Php manual for array_rand :- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php